# Heap and Stack issues with Structs - C programming

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, allocation, stack-memory

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

struct B 
{ 
    int _arr[5]; 
}; 
struct A 
{ 
    struct B *_pb_arr; 
}; 


int main() 
{ 
    int i,j; 
    struct B b; 
    struct B *pb = (struct B*)malloc(sizeof (struct B)); 
    *pb = b; 

    struct A a; 
    a._pb_arr = (struct B*)malloc(sizeof (struct B)*2); 
    a._pb_arr[0] = b; //first question
    a._pb_arr[1] = *pb; //second question

    for (i=0;i<2;++i) 
    { 
        for (j=0;j<5;++j) 
        { 
            a._pb_arr[i]._arr[j] = i; 
        } 
    } 
    struct A a2 = a; 

    for (i=0;i<2;++i) 
    { 
        for (j=0;j<5;++j) 
        { 
            printf ("%d, ", a2._pb_arr[i]._arr[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

My question is: why on: `a._pb_arr[0] = b;`
The assignment is on stack.
and on the next line:  `a._pb_arr[1] = *pb`
The assignment is on the heap?

It seems like `a.pb_arr` was allocated on the heap and each assignment is on the heap also.

Comment: This depends what you mean by "the assignment is on the (stack|heap)". (That's not standard terminology.) The first assignment is copying a structure from the stack to the heap, while the second assignment is copying a structure from one part of the heap to another.

Comment: Your question is not altogether clear, but you want to know why the structs always get copied to the heap by the assignment, even though one was originally defined in the stack?

Comment: So I understated you both I think... In both cases it's copied to the heap right?

Comment: @rukah So I understated you both I think... In both cases it's copied to the heap right?

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: This makes no sense. What does it mean for an assignment to be "on stack" or "on the heap"?

Comment: @rukah So maybe I didn't understood what I was asked,

Comment: @ruakh I was asked - Where the memory is allocated for saving the content of a._pb_arr when the line is finished, so what did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assignments aren't on the stack or heap, objects are.

Object `a` is on the stack because it's created like this:

```
struct A a;
```

To create objects on the heap, you have to allocate memory for them using `malloc`.

So although `a` is on the stack, `a._pb_arr` will be on the heap. You have to explicitly `free` the memory when you're done. Following the same reasoning, `b` is on the stack and `pb` is on the heap.

When you assign the objects in the array `a._pb_arr`, the values will be copied, but they still remain on the heap, since you allocated memory to `a._pb_arr`.

To prevent memory leaks, you have to use `free` for both `a._pb_arr` and `pb`.

Comment: But it's not like on: a._pb_arr[0]=b, it goes to the first place allocated for struct B, and then copied b into it?

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm I understood that the answer was a bit vague, so I edited it. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks, but look what I wrote to "rukah", I think it's more clearer for what I meant